# Strange picture noise at the beginning of live stream

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, rtsp

I have a SurfaceView and I'm displaying a live stream (RTSP) in it.

Everything is fine except, most of the time, during the first seconds or minutes of playback there is a **gray noise/overlay** which either disappears completely all at once or gradually clears (**starting at the spots where some motion takes place in the picture** - see the attached screenshots below).

I'm pretty sure it is not an android issue as the same thing happens even if I watch the stream using VLC on my PC, but judging from the way the noise clears, I have a feeling there should be a way I could programmatically "clear/refresh" the picture.

**Do you have an idea how that could be accomplished?**

this is the stream: rtsp://193.40.133.138:80/live/juras-erglis

Here are some screenshots, how the picture clears progressively:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an initial key frame, so the deltas are being performed against the initial buffer contents. Once enough time passes or enough motion occurs, the encoder emits another key frame and you get in sync.

Satellite and digital cable TV systems typically send a key frame 2x per second, so that you never have to wait more than half a second to sync up with the video stream.  I don't know if there's much you can do except put up a "waiting for sync" message.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) has some background.